# C99 client communicating with a Java Server

Tags: java, c, sockets

I'm trying to get a C99 client to communicate with a Java server. However the data being received by the Java server is not the same as the data that was transmitted. (ie. @x�@Óﬂ/ú.��@¨�����������������Û¢ÁBp‘ˇ¡`Ôﬂ/)

I've contemplated that it's an encoding issue however I've hit a brick wall. I've tried testing the two programs to conclude that the Java server is able to communicate with a Java client and the C client is able to communicate with a C server.

However I cannot get the Java server to communicate with a C client.

Java code:

```
serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);  
Socket sock = serverSocket.accept();                               

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));

String inputString = in.readLine();
System.out.println(inputString);
```

C code:

```
struct sockaddr_in sin;
struct hostent *host;

host = gethostbyname(hostname);

bzero(&(sin.sin_zero),8); 
sin.sin_port = htons(port);
sin.sin_addr = *((struct in_addr *)host->h_addr);
sin.sin_family = AF_INET;

sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

if(connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&sin,sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) == -1)
```

...

```
send(sock, &message, strlen(message)+1, 0);
```

**EDIT: I've tried sending the word 'TEST' between the two hosts without success.**

**FIXED: I had an ampersand in front of the message variable as I was passing it.**

**Should have been:**

```
send(sock, message, strlen(message)+1, 0);
```

Comment: What is the encoding of the message from C?

Comment: So my answer were correct then ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not wrong you have something like:

```
char *message = "Hello";
```

When you send by:

```
send(sock, &message, strlen(message)+1, 0);
           |
           +---- Err.
```

You send address of message and not the message itself, further you set the length to length of message and such padding with garbage.

If you do this instead:

```
send(sock, message, strlen(message)+1, 0);
```

It should work.

Or use `char message[] = "Hello";` …

---

To further dissect server data you could do something like:

```
        int i = 0;
        for (char ch : inputString.toCharArray()) {
            System.out.printf("%2d: 0x%02X o%03o %3d %c%n",
                i++,
                (int)ch & 0xff,
                (int)ch & 0xff,
                (int)ch & 0xff,
                Character.isISOControl(ch) ? '.' : ch
            );
        }
```

or

```
        buf = inputLine.getBytes(/* charset  */);
        for (i = 0; i < buf.length; ++i) {
```

etc.

```
Client siad: Hello
 0: 0x00 o000   0 .
 1: 0x48 o110  72 H
 2: 0x65 o145 101 e
 3: 0x6C o154 108 l
 4: 0x6C o154 108 l
 5: 0x6F o157 111 o
```

Using &message:

```
Client said: `�
 0: 0x60 o140  96 `
 1: 0xEF o357 239 ￯
 2: 0xBF o277 191 ﾿
 3: 0xBD o275 189 ﾽ
 4: 0x04 o004   4 .
 5: 0x08 o010   8 .
```

---

Another hack/debug/thing one can do is something like:

```
    while (true) {
        in.mark(128);
        if ((inputLine = in.readLine()) == null)
            continue;

        System.out.println("Response: " + inputLine);

        in.reset();
        i = 0;
        while (in.ready()) {
            c = in.read();
            System.out.printf("%2d: 0x%02X o%03o %3d %c%n",
                i++,
                c, c, c,
                Character.isISOControl((char) c) ? '.' : (char)c
            );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if C99 provides a standard for encoding but I suppose it's implementation specific. It could be `US-ASCII` for example.

What happens is that a Java `InputStreamReader` (or output) uses the default charset specified somewhere in the OS or the Java installation (not sure where) so it may differ compared to the one used by the C program.

The best thing you can do is to test various encodings, the `InputStreamReader` class indeed provides a specific constructor:

```
public InputStreamReader(InputStream in, Charset cs)
```

in which you are allowed to specify which charset you want to use. Take a look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) for possible charsets.

Comment: The C client is using the US-ASCII charset according to nl_langinfo(CODESET) so it's not a character encoding issue. I have also forced the Java server to use this character set using InputStreamReader without success.

Answer (score 1):

You also have to look at endian disparity: Java uses [network order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Endianness_in_networking), while the C host may not. `ByteBuffer`, illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2212025/230513), may help.

Answer (score 0):

your problem looks like the byte alignment

in your `C` client you need to convert the **host to network byte order**.

use

```
uint32_t htonl(uint32_t hostlong);

uint16_t htons(uint16_t hostshort);

uint32_t ntohl(uint32_t netlong);

uint16_t ntohs(uint16_t netshort);
```

Comment: I'm sending text, not raw digits.

Comment: pls refer to this question for sending the char arrays http://stackoverflow.com/q/526030/143897

Comment: Sending the word "test" from the client to the server didn't work. The message didn't have any numbers so I doubt that is the issue.